# Unable to write "<" and ">" in spanish layout on us keyboard, but it was not like that some days ago

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have this laptop that has a US keyboard but I use the "ES" (Spanish from Spain) keymap.

I could write the `<` and `>` (smaller and greater than) brackets until a few days ago, using the combination <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+[<kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd>]. I was used to this and presented no problem for me.

Some days ago I updated my system (Arch Linux) and now, instead of these signs I got a smaller, "guillemet-like" signs, these:  `‹` `›` very weird and useless, as most programming languages and Bash don't recognize them.

Was there a change of standard? How can I type them now?